# Additivity of Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

[It is stated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology) that for $\chi(X)$ the Euler characteristic of a space $X$, and $Z \subset Y \subset X$, it holds that:

$$ \chi (X,Z) = \chi(X,Y) + \chi(Y,Z)$$

How does this follow from the exact sequences associated to the relative homologies? I assume one uses the exact sequences $$\cdots \to H_j (Y) \to H_j (X) \to H_j (X,Y) \to \cdots$$ $$\cdots \to H_j (Z) \to H_j (Y) \to H_j (Y,Z) \to \cdots$$and the excision theorem, but I am not sure how to show this properly.

Comment: Use instead the long exact sequence of the triple $(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: How is that exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an exact sequence $\dots \to V_k \to V_{k-1} \to \dots$, assuming that all of the groups involved are finitely generated, then the alternating sum of the ranks is zero: $\sum (-1)^k \text{rank}\, V_k = 0$. Apply that formula to the long exact sequence of the triple $Z \subset Y \subset X$:
$$
\dots \to H_n(Y,Z) \to H_n(X,Z) \to H_n(X,Y) \to H_{n-1}(Y,Z) \to ...
$$
One way to prove the fact about ranks in an exact sequence is to tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$, turning it into an exact sequence of vector spaces and converting rank to dimension. Then apply the rank-nullity theorem. For the vector space case, see the [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255384/dimensions-of-vector-spaces-in-an-exact-sequence), for example.